# Python-less Pi Pico toolchain in Windows

Tags: pi-pico, c++, toolchain

Is there any way to build a C++ Raspberry Pi Pico binary without having to install Python. It's quite heavyweight and feels quite unnecessary (I do like tidy toolchains without huge bloat and an additional attack surface on my machine).

Note that I'm on Windows, and do realise that non-Windows toolchains may not require Python at all

Comment: Thanks for your question. I'm sure everyone needed the "comic relief" you provided: You profess to worry about Python "bloat" and security concerns, and then (after two answers) you think to inform us that you're a Windows user :)  LOL      I hope you stick around - we all appreciate your sense of humor.

Comment: Yeah, some of us do have 0 choice on the operating system we're required to use. Must be nice to not have requirements dictated by higher authorities. Not that it would matter, as the software I wish to connect the device to only works on Windows

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi Pico SDK includes a command-line toolchain for building C/C++ projects without relying on Python. The Raspberry Pi Pico SDK is a software development kit that allows you to write programs for RP2040-based devices such as the Raspberry Pi Pico in C, C++ or assembly language. You can download it. I believe it will solve your purpose.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific. My understanding was that it is the Pico SDK that requires the installation of Python in order to build the binary, even if your code is not Python code

Comment: Raspberry Pi Pico SDK traditionally utilizes Python scripts for building projects. However, there are alternatives to using the Python-based build system. For example, you can use the CMake build system directly with the Pico SDK. https://dev.to/admantium/getting-started-with-raspberry-pico-and-cmake-33h

Comment: I am indeed using the CMake system in the Pico SDK, however it complains about missing Python. Apparently Python is still used in a minor obscure corner of the toolchain to do not much (padding and checksum, apparently). I was hoping someone may have found a way around that

Comment: I just realised that you are correct if running on Linux. I neglected to mention that I'm on Windows. Sorry about that